# Are there any decent PyBrain tutorials out there?

Tags: python, pybrain

So, PyBrain definitely seems like it has a lot of great tools and functionality(s) to be used. Sadly, it's documentation/'tutorial' is....very........weaK? And it is very hard to determine how to do what one wishes to do.

Is there any resource for learning PyBrain's API better? Or is it all just trial and error learning?

Thank you in advance....

Comment: The question is just fine. Why closed? Open it.

Comment: conspiracy :D 
I would appreciate a bit more documentation too!

Comment: agree.. good question